# With useSWR how can I compare data before and after revalidation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr, use-swr

Using Next.js and through useSWR I am pulling data from an endpoint every 30s using an automatic revalidation interval (https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval). In the data that is being pulled, there is an array that on every pull will have between 1-4 more items since the last pull. How can I get the previous array.length and compare it to the new, revalidated array.length so that I have a variable that counts the differential?

The idea is to have the new items show up in an interval within those 30s. Suppose I have the array as 'messages', this is what I came to:

```
const prevMessagesLength = ?
const [message, setMessage] = useState(messages[0])
useEffect(() => {
        let length = messages.length - prevMessagesLength
        let delay = (30 / length) * 1000
        for (var i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
            showMessage(i)
        }
        function showMessage(i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                setMessage(messages[i])
            }, (length - i) * delay)
        }
}, [messages])
```

Answer (score 0):

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/api

Based on the offical document of swr, there's an option 'compare(a,b)' on useSWR hook.

```
comparison function used to detect when returned data has changed, to avoid spurious rerenders. By default, stable-hash is used.
```

This option is origianlly for comparing existing data and new data, the point is that you can access both data in this compare function.

I think you could use like this below

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetchData = async () => {
    // Your data fetching logic here
};

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [differenceCount, setDifferenceCount] = useState(0);

    const compareFunction = (prevData, newData) => {
        // Implement your logic to count differences
        const diffCount = calculateDifferences(prevData, newData);
        setDifferenceCount(diffCount);

        // Return true if data is different, otherwise false
        return diffCount > 0;
    };

    const { data, error } = useSWR('api/data', fetchData, {
        compare: compareFunction
    });

    const calculateDifferences = (prevData, newData) => {
        // Your logic to calculate the number of differences
        // This will depend on the structure of your data
    };

    if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
    if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Difference Count: {differenceCount}</p>
            {/* Render your component */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Might work, but it is a horrendous hack. Using an extension point that is supposed to perform a comparison to actually do side effects is not very obvious.

Comment: @erikkallen Thanks for feedback. Is there any problems that could happen due to this usage? I thought using this option would be better than just using useEffect and useState as described in the question which is actually sideEffect and not that clean.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, but using things in a way they are not intended is, in general, a recipe for problems that will show up when you least want it.